# Why was I told to review my review?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I approved [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13354991), as did 3 of the 4 other reviewers; but when I next came to review something I was told my review wasn't helpful and that I should see what I should have done better. Given that I voted to approve (and would again, there's an improvement in grammar) and the edit was approved... what gives?

Comment: How does removing the part that says the poster hasn't tried and and adding in a comment saying they hope it works do anything to improve the post?

Comment: Given that you voted to approve, and would again, it seems appropriate that you should get a timeout from reviewing...

Comment: And just because three people approved an edit doesn't mean that it definitively should have been approved...

Comment: To expand on what @honk said, action isn't usually taken against reviewers of suggested edits that got *rejected* in the end. So if you see one of these messages, it is without exception because you *and the other approvers* **all got it wrong**.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

That post isn't even an answer.  It should just be deleted as being not an answer, not edited to try to address a few minor grammatical errors that don't address the root problem of it not being an answer.

Saying, "I hope this can help you" is just noise; it should just be *removed*, rather than playing with the grammatical phrasing of it.

"I myself never tried it" *isn't* actually noise and *shouldn't* be removed from the post.  It's something that at least gives me *some* information when reading this post (namely that it needs to be deleted with prejudice because not only is it not an answer, but this person clearly doesn't even know what they're talking about, by their own admission).

Comment: Not only that, but the editor *changed* it from "but I myself never tried it" to "and it works". That's just putting words in the author's mouth.

Comment: @BoltClock They changed it to "I hope [...] it works", which is different from, "it works".

Comment: Oh, that's right: "I hope this can help you and it works." My misread.

Comment: Is it "(I hope this can help you) and (it works)" or "I hope (this can help you and it works)" ?

Answer (score 24):

As others have noted, that was a terrible answer; I've deleted it.

But more importantly, the edit that you approved *removed information* from the answer. It's a bit hard to argue that the edit made it worse, since it was already so bad... But I do feel knowing that the answer being given *hasn't been tested by the person posting it* is potentially helpful and thus stripping it out has the chance of costing someone else time on an untested solution.

Think of editing as having something akin to the Hippocratic Oath: first, do no harm.

Answer (score 8):

So what if the grammar is improved? It's still a link-only answer (one that even the post author is unsure of themself, at that). The edit does absolutely nothing to alleviate that, and is therefore pointless.

Even if no one else other than the author of the answer knows how exactly the link should be expanded for context (which again based on the answer I'm not even confident the author themself knows), that's just a reason for the editor to refrain from editing this particular answer. They should find another answer that's worth editing or at the very least, actually salvageable.